# Custom CSS3 Variable Not Working in Polymer 1.0 Starter Kit

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

-My css3 vars are not showing. Here is the setup (scripts are removed and assumed all is well):

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
 <style>
  .tester {
    color: var(--my-app-tester-color);
  }
 </style>
 <template>
  <div class="tester">abc</div>
 </template>
</dom-module>

// app-theme.html:

<style is="custom-style">
 my-app {
  --my-app-tester-color: red;
 }
</style>
```

I am following [Rob's Polycast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omASiF85JzI) tutorial but nothing works.

Comment: You missed an endquote on line 8 and an extra dash on line 16.

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal Thanks for those missing thing but I have done that and still same.

Comment: Seems working for me http://jsbin.com/hedutu/edit?html,output.

Comment: Try to see if your imports are correct.

Comment: My imports are working as if set global color for other elements and they work. I'm refactoring to use variables. The app-theme is vulcanized.

Comment: I just can't see anything wrong to be honest.

Comment: It appears that I've had the style tag inside the template. Silly me. It now works.